# Express session using redis store couldn't create session

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis

I'm using Express 4.13.1 with Redis as session store.

```
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore,
    secret: '...',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

It worked at first, but then it didn't work (after upgrading node.js). Using default store(memory) works fine, but using RedisStore, session is not being created. This is the code to create session :

```
router.post('/admin/login', (req, res, next) => {
    Auth.compare(..., () => {
        req.session.authorized = true;
        req.session.userId = id;

        console.log(req.session);    // It prints well. Session is created

        res.redirect('/admin/main');
    });
});
```

at that moment, session was changed:

```
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  authorized: true,
  userId: '...'}
```

but after that, session wasn't created:

```
router.get('/admin/main', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.session);
    ...
});
```

printing session:

```
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true }
}
```

I used session.save manually, but it didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: @FurkanO thanks for fixing my words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working with redis one might check a few points in the app to solve a problem like this. First of all, check that you browser gets the cookie, for instance by checking resources -> cookies **on browser**.

- Check the expiration date and see the session id there.

Secondly, check the redis for the corresponding key, if key exists and the expiration of key from **redis-cli** :

- All keys : `keys *`
- Value by key : `get key (sess:PMlu4s1PYHnSZXBMSoJGLgjNSGXq_s-g is a key for me)`
- Check when your key expires : `ttl key`

There might be one of the following problems :

- You might have configured redis inappropriately
- You might have configured redis ttl inappropriately, for instance
  your ttl value should be in seconds, whereas cookie maxAge is in
  miliseconds.

Instead of asking for your server.js code, I recommend you to follow these steps to check if everything is okay with expiration or at least session is created .

Comment: I checked cookies on my browser, and it created well. And Expires/Max-Age value is "Session" <- I don't know what that means. I'm using default expires(in express doc saids, it makes persistence cookie, and I want use this). Also I'm using default parameters for redis store and never changed or configured.

Comment: I guess the problem is your redis config. You might try to check if the same sessionid is available in redis from redis-cli.

Comment: I just checked redis, and getting all keys returns **(empty list or set)**. I didn't configured redis after I installed it. Why this happening?

Comment: Also I asked my problem to connect-redis github issues, and someone tried my code and that was worked. I also worked before I updated node.js. :(

Comment: create a small server and try features again. Npm install everything from scratch.